# Octave - Generate Square Wave (Signal/Pulse)

Tags: signals, octave, wave, pulse

I want to generate a periodic square wave (Signal/Pulse) in Octave/Matlab with the following properties:

1. Amplitude of 0.5
2. Period of 0.02 seconds
3. Average (Mittelwert) of 0.5

So far I have this:

```
T = 1/10;
t = linspace(0,T,1001);
y = square(2*pi*50*t);
plot(t,y);
axis([0 0.1 -1.5 1.5]);
```

That produces this result:

[image]

As you may see the amplitude is not correct but since I am a total newbie, I have no idea how to fix it. The period is correct but I'm still not sure what is this average value in the graphical point of view...

Comment: `square` creates a square wave with values [-1 and 1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/square.html). Would something like `plot(t, 0.5*y)` be what you are looking for?

Comment: why can't use matlab and octave tags together? they are two similar and related programming environments; some questions may be related to both, such as porting one to another.

Comment: @SardarUsama Since both Matlab and Octave are related to my questions in the same way and can do the same I don't think that I must edit my tags... I am doing it currently with Octave because I was not at home where I have paid license for Matlab...

Comment: ***1.*** MATLAB and Octave are similar but not always one to one. If you are using Octave, a solution in MATLAB that doesn't work in Octave will not be useful for you. Same goes the other way around. However if you want your code to run on both platforms, you need to explicitly state that in your question. ***2.*** Images of code are not acceptable on StackOverflow

Comment: @SardarUsama Okay, when you so strongly disagree with the way that I provided my question I will edit it, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: In the past, there have been multiple such occurrence when a person was using Octave but said he was using MATLAB. And so we provided MATLAB solutions. Since the OP was using Octave, those solutions didn't work and we all ended up wasting our time. That's why the tag descriptions of both MATLAB and Octave explicitly say to tag only the one which you are using unless the question is explicitly about the similarities or differences between the two. Thanks for understanding and fixing your question.

Comment: I was thinking since I have both applications and use them both for study purposes, that any answer might be helpful because I can test them in Matlab respectively in Octave. After your comment, I've decided to continue with the use of Octave only because of several reasons and therefore I have edited my question following the guidelines provided by you.

Comment: If you need a solution that should work on both platforms then it is okay to go with both tags but you need to write that explicitly that you are looking for such a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be pretty fast and straightforward to write, checkout my implementation.

```
function y=square(t)
% License: public domain
t=t*(1/(pi));
y=ones(size(t));
y(find(bitand(abs(floor(t)),1)))=-1;
```

a test script:

```
t = -0.02:.001:.0625;
y = 0.5*square(2*pi*30*t);
plot(t,y,'-o')
```

Comment: It is probably a good idea to avoid defining a " `square`" function when `square` is a built-in function.

Comment: oops, I thought OP said such function does not exist on Octave. my bad.

Comment: @FangQ It works almost as I wanted but the lines are not exactly straight or at least that's what I see, check here https://ibb.co/7J9xCjN

Comment: the slope is due to sample spacing - the smaller the spacing, the steeper it looks. reducing the step size of t and try again.